# Is there a way to hide or disable promiscuous interface in Centos 7?

Tags: centos7, promiscuous

I use Lynis to audit my Centos 7 server security and I got a complain:

! Found promiscuous interface [NETW-3015]
- Details : eth0
- Solution : Determine if this mode is required or whitelist interface in profile
https://cisofy.com/lynis/controls/NETW-3015/

How do I completely disable the promiscuous mode?

Edit 1 (I found better way to check promiscuous mode look at Edit 2):

I check the promiscuous mode using the following command:

```
sudo ip link show eth0
```

The output appeared doesn't contain any promiscuous mode enabled:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

============================================

Edit 2:

When using this command:

```
ip -details addr
```

I can see the output showing promiscuity 1 (which means it is enabled):

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000 

link/ether 64:00:6a:73:bf:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 1
openvswitch_slave
```

How do I completely disabled promiscuous mode in Centos 7?

Comment: It's already disabled. Your test is broken.

Comment: Hai, it's not disabled. Using the command ip -details addr it shows the flag promiscuity 1. I think this is where Lynis complains.

Comment: You forgot to mention you were running Open vSwitch. That is important information.

Comment: Is there away to turn it off when Running on Open vSwitch? Actually I use Linode VPS. I also tried changing several kernels that doesn't help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found out why. To help others:

I had a startup script that enable arpwatch to listen to the eth0 after rebuilding my VPS from scratch and this process is the reason that turning on the promiscuous mode.